# Trying to launch Twitter in Safari if app redirect fails

Tags: ios, twitter, swift, openurl

I have been attempting to add a follow button within my app so that users are able to follow me on Twitter for support and updates.

What I would like to happen is for the Twitter app to be launched if available and if not, the the Safari would launch and would redirect to my app's Twitter page.

At the moment I have the code for launching my Twitter page through the app working, however it is not working if the user does not have Twitter installed.

Here is the tutorial I was following:

http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-create-a-twitter-follow-button-in-your-ios-app/

Here is my code:

```
    @IBAction func followOnTwitter(sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL.URLWithString("twitter://user?screen_name=AffordIt_App")) {
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL.URLWithString("https://twitter.com/AffordIt_App")) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing not operator in

```
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL.URLWithString("twitter://user?screen_name=AffordIt_App"))
```

cause it should try to open browser if can't find the twitter app.

Recheck once.

Comment: Ah. Pretty obvious really. I can't check it properly right now since I don't have a device to test it on, but it seems to work given that I was redirected to Safari on the simulator. Thanks a lot!